# Convert result of aggregation to string

Tags: django

I am using aggregate and Sum to determine the number of hours I have worked in each month. I have it working, but the "hours" variable always has extra content in it!

I should add, I am a newbie at django and I got most of this code from here ([Django beginner: How to query in django ORM to calculate fields based on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548638/django-beginner-how-to-query-in-django-orm-to-calculate-fields-based-on-dates)).

My code:

```
hours = ""
work_data = ""
month_data = ""

for month in range(1,13):
  entries_per_month = Mydata.objects.filter(myTimePeriod__month=month).filter(myResource="James")
  hours = str(entries_per_month.aggregate(value=Sum('myHoursLogged')))
  month_data = month_data + "'" + str(month) + "',"
  work_data = work_data + hours + ","
```

I look at the results of work_data:

```
work_data
```

This gives me a result of `{'value': Decimal('136.80')},{'value': Decimal('146.40')}`,

I need it in the format: `136.80, 146.40`  (This is the format required by the charting library). I have tried using `str()` to convert it but it doesnt seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is not useful here, because your data is a list of dictionaries. You just need to process that and get the results:

```
hours = ','.join(str(v['value']) for v in entries_per_month)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand this. Where would I insert this line? What should i be using for `'value'` ?

Comment: You put it in the code above in place of your line that has `str`. And I have no idea what you mean by saying "what should i be using for 'value'". Note that this is fairly basic Python, if you're struggling here you should do a Python tutorial.